# Use css counter in calc

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I have a list **ul>li*5** (not always the same amount). I set a  counter for which I get:

1 2 3 4 5

```
li:nth-child(n):before {
  counter-increment: skill;
  content: counter(skill);
  color: white;
}
```

**The Question** Can I use the *counter(skill)* inside a **calc()** or can I add units to it **px em rem % ms s**

I have tried:

```
transition: all 250ms linear #{counter(skill)} * 1s;
transition: all 250ms linear counter(skill) * 1s;
```

I want to have the delay increased for example:

```
li 1s delay
li 2s delay
li 3s delay
li 4s delay
li Xs delay
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Will there be a way to do this using the **nth-child(N)**

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> The Question Can I use the counter(skill) inside a calc()

No. You can't.

The `calc` function does not permit the use of `counter` functions as its components. From the specs here - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation:

> Components of a
>   [`calc()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-calc) expression
>   can be literal values or
>   [`attr()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-attr) or
>   [`calc()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-calc)
>   expressions.

There have been many requests for this but always declined. The underlying reason seems to be that the `counter()` function represents (outputs) a `<string>` and hence cannot be used directly in `calc`. Moreover, the counters are considered very expensive for the browsers.

Reference:  https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Aug/0082.html

However, there have been proposals for adding a `counter-value()` function which would return the value as integer and could be used in `calc`. See here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-functions (Scroll down to see Issue 4).

So as of now, you cannot use `counter` inside of `calc` and the `counter-value` does not exist yet.

Comment: The W3C issue "[enable the use of counter() inside calc()](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1026)"

Comment: No attr() anymore

Answer (score 23):

This wouldn't necessarily be an elegant solution, but you could solve it with nth-child or using css variables. Code below, or see here: https://codepen.io/goodship11/pen/XBVeez

### nth-child version:

```css
li { 
  opacity: 0; 
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(200,50,255,.2);
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
}
li:nth-child(even) { background-color: rgba(200,50,255,.5); }

@keyframes fade { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }

li { animation: fade 1.5s ease-in forwards; }

/* Since you're doing an animation, chances our the number 
of elements will be small, so you can just pre-define for however 
many versions using nth-child. This wouldn't work for use cases 
where, for example, you want a percentage of the whole instead 
of a fixed number */

li:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 1s; }
li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 2s; }
li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 3s; }
li:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 4s; }
li:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 5s; }
li:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 6s; }
li:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 7s; }
li:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 8s; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
  <li>Thing 3</li>
  <li>Thing 4</li>
  <li>Thing 5</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS variables version:

```css
li { 
  opacity: 0; 
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(200,50,255,var(--fader));
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
}
@keyframes fade { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }

li { animation: fade 1.5s ease-in forwards; }

/* Below is an alternative approach using the same variable 
from the opacity. I added in a scaling factor to show how you 
can use one variable for multiple things in cases like this.  */ 

:root {--factor: .5; }
li { animation-delay: calc(10s * var(--fader) * var(--factor));}
```

```html
<ul>

  <!-- You can define the variable in-line, useful for in 
cases where you're writing the html manually but don't want to 
mess with the stylesheet. '--fader: .1' defines the variable 
for that instance of the li -->

  <li style="--fader: .1;">Thing 1</li>
  <li style="--fader: .2;">Thing 2</li>
  <li style="--fader: .3;">Thing 3</li>
  <li style="--fader: .4;">Thing 4</li>
  <li style="--fader: .5;">Thing 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on goodship11's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596542/8112776), except allowing for a dynamic number of elements (to avoid the need to create a potentially infinite number of `nth-child` css rules).

## Dynamic version:

The example uses jQuery (so it's shorter) but it could just as easily done in plain ol' JavaScript (see the edit).

```js
var i=0; 
$('#myList li').each(function(){
  this.style.setProperty('--n',i++);
})
```

```css
li{opacity:0; animation:fadeIn 1s calc(var(--n)*1s) 1 forwards;}
@keyframes fadeIn{to{opacity:1}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
  <li>Thing 3</li>
  <li>Thing 4</li>
  <li>Thing 5</li>
</ul>
```

...or the loops could be written as a one-liner without the need for a variable, by instead using the element's index number:

`$('#myList li').each(function(){this.style.setProperty('--n', Array.from($('#myList li')).indexOf(this))});`

---

**EDIT:** while I'm at it, here's the **"plain" JavaScript** equivalent:

```js
const lis=Array.from(myList.getElementsByTagName('li'));
for(var n=0; n<lis.length; n++){
  lis[n].style.setProperty('--n', n);
}
```

```css
li{opacity:0; animation:fadeIn 1s calc(var(--n)*1s) 1 forwards;}
@keyframes fadeIn{to{opacity:1}}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
  <li>Thing 3</li>
  <li>Thing 4</li>
  <li>Thing 5</li>
</ul>
```