# CSS Counter and Animation delay

Tags: css

I wonder if there is a simple CSS solution to make an animation delay depending on the count of elements. I've tried something like this.

```css
/* fade in from left */

@keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

ul {
  counter-reset: items;
}

li {
  counter-increment: items;
  animation: myAnimation;
  animation-delay: counter(items) * .2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have a solution which does not include javascript or multiple css classes?

Comment: Nope...not possible with CSS.

Comment: If you want to avoid dirty and longish hacks that involve positioning with `nth-child` to declare all timings possible from 1 to infinity, the answer is no, i guess

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539203/use-css-counter-in-calc

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp try this

Comment: Not possible yet! Here's the full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43540570/661643